# Tidy complicated messy data into long data format in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2, tidyverse

I could simply do this manually by creating arrays, transposing them and combining them, or maybe by the `base::reshape`. However, I would like to migrate to the ultimate truth by jumping dead into the Tidyverse, but now I am drowning.

I have a data like this:

```
id A B
1  2 3
1  3 4
1  5 5
1  - 6
1  - 7
2 ...
```

And I would like to have this:

```
id A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
1  2  3  5  3  4  5  6  7
2 ...
```

The actual values in variable `A` and `B` are arbitrary above, and my actual data have more than 10 A and B pairs, with more than 500 `id`s. Obviously, I am pushing the data into the "long" format, but this makes much sense for my data. Also, once they are arranged as that, shaping them into the long format shouldn't be hard, right?

Any idiomatic tidyverse way of doing it? Would be nice if we can flatten out the whole thing (with multiple similar `A`ish and `B`ish columns) in a single function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "id A B
1  2 3
1  3 4
1  5 5
1  NA 6
1  NA 7",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(Label, Value, -id) %>%
  drop_na(Value) %>%
  group_by(id, Label) %>%
  mutate(Label_Id = 1:n()) %>%
  unite(Col, Label, Label_Id, sep = "") %>%
  spread(Col, Value)
```

#### Update: Create a function to generalize the process

Based on the comment, the OP asks for a more "generalized" approach, which I may not fully understand, but here I demonstrated how to convert the above code to a function and design three test cases. The function `flatten` has one argument, which is the input `tbl` or a `data frame`. The input `tbl` or `data frame` should have column as `id, A, B, C, D ...`.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Process the data
flatten <- function(dt){
  dt %>%
    gather(Label, Value, -id) %>%
    drop_na(Value) %>%
    group_by(id, Label) %>%
    mutate(Label_Id = 1:n()) %>%
    unite(Col, Label, Label_Id, sep = "") %>%
    spread(Col, Value)
}


### Test Case 1
test1 <- data_frame(id = rep(1, 5),
                    A = c(2, 3, 5, NA, NA),
                    B = 3:7)
test1_result <- flatten(test1)

### Test Case 2
test2 <- data_frame(id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 8)),
                    A = c(2, 3, 5, NA, NA, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, NA, 10, 12),
                    B = 3:15)
test2_result <- flatten(test2)

### Test Case 3
test3 <- data_frame(id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 8)),
                    A = c(2, 3, 5, NA, NA, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, NA, 10, 12),
                    B = 3:15,
                    C = c(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), each = 2), NA, NA, NA),
                    D = seq(2, 26, 2))

test3_result <- flatten(test3)
```

Comment: How does this generalize to flattening moreA1, B1 etc. variables?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. This solution should work even if there are more rows than the example you provided.

Comment: Thanks you, and I can see it can deal with more rows (id). However, how do you scale up if there are similar many columns like A and B above? I imagine you could write a function that takes column names as inputs, and spits out flattened data for all the columns.

Comment: Please see my update. Notice that using `dplyr` to design a function is a completely new topic. If you want to learn more, I suggest you see `vignette("programming")` to learn more about programming with `dplyr`. Post a new question when you have a clearly defined problem statement.

Comment: That looks like a magic, yay! And yes, composing functions with dplyr seems not one of the most obvious paradigm. Thanks!